# How do I create orbital circles around a letter like on the sphere?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

[image: existing logo]

I need to create something like this, and I don't know how to! How can I create "orbiting" circles around a sphere similar to the symbol for an atom?

Comment: Hi jacob, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. As-is, your question is likely to be put on hold. We could help you better if you showed us what you've tried already and what didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the transform effect which would allow you little less adjustment to fine tune the shape of the orbits.[image]

this way all the other orbits are linked to the shape of the first.

then you would object->expand apperance them and cut them to adjust the stacking

Answer (score 1):

I created this effect by placing ellipse that was duplicated and rotated 4 times at 45 degree (30sec operation)

[image]

Next, you cut the ellipses to the sub-shapes and place them on top or below the ball shape.

Comment: thanks thats awesome!this site is seriously useful...appreciate that.

Comment: @jacobyoung welcome to GD.  If you find the answer useful please make sure to upvote.  If you find the answer has answered your question please make sure to accept it as the answer to your question.